# How to check dimensions of a numpy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I want to do something like this inside a function:

```
if image.shape == 2 dimensions
    return image # this image is grayscale
else if image.shape = 3 dimensions
    return image # image is either RGB or YCbCr colorspace
```

Here, the image is a numpy array. I am not able to define that checking condition. I am really stuck at this point. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What if you use the title for google search?

Comment: Did you even try to look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) for numpy arrays?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[numpy.array.shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) is a tuple of array dimensions.  You can compute the length of a tuple and that will give the number of dimensions.

```
if len(image.shape) == 2:
    return image # this image is grayscale
elif len(image.shape) == 3:
    return image # image is either RGB or YCbCr colorspace
```

Numpy arrays also have a [`ndim`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html) attribute.

```
if image.ndim == 2:
    return image # this image is grayscale
elif image.ndim == 3:
    return image # image is either RGB or YCbCr colorspace
```

Answer (score 0):

### THERE IS ONE MORE "*hidden-DIMENSION*" OF THE PROBLEM :

Numpy has a few performance-motivated tricks, that may confuse you, if not taking due care of:

There are tricks that **`np.view()`** creates, as a ***view*** into a "*foreign*"-owned data, which actually means there has appeared a **form of *hidden* sharing**, which may pretty ugly surprise you if some operations on already "**`return()`**-ed" `image` store any modification into a just-`.view()`-created *view*. In such cases your code will silently damage the "***foreign***"-data, because you did not realise or notice that while the **`image`** reports correctly both the `image.{shape|ndim}`, yet it does not "***have***" its own data, but provides just a view through a "periscope-alike-window" into the original data, still "***owned***" somewhere else by someone else ( here, a write into `image`, like in an exemplary assignment of **`image[0,0] = -1`** will actually "*write-through*" the **`-1`** to get it stored into the "*throat*" of **`A`**-s `A.data`, being actually a `<read-write buffer for 0x7efe9ff73800, size 7372800, offset 0 at 0x7efe9ff6cbf0>` implementor-zone of the actual write-storage operation resulting in modification taking place in **`A`**'s data
 )

This side-effect of **`.view()`**-s is both very **powerful** (if used knowingly, where intended, for performance or other reasons) yet also very **awful** to detect/debug (if not detected in the code design phase and just hunting the devils tail once the "*source*"-data get damaged without knowing who does turned the so far clear and sound design wreck havoc "***foreign***&**safely-owned**"-data from behind a curtain ... <sub>that may take and indeed takes pretty long to detect such hidden sharing write-throughs ... if they take place without your prior intent</sub> )

```
>>> A = np.arange( 3*640*480 ).reshape( 3, 640, 480 )
>>> A.shape
(3, 640, 480)
>>> A.ndim
3

>>> B = A.view()  # ENFORCE B BECOME A VIEW() ON AN ARRAY
>>> B.shape       #         B MIMICS AN ARRAY, WHILE IT IS NOT AN ARRAY
(3, 640, 480)
>>> B.ndim        #         B MIMICS AN ARRAY, WHILE IT IS NOT AN ARRAY
3
>>> B.flags       #         B MIMICS AN ARRAY, WHILE IT IS NOT AN ARRAY
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : False
  OWNDATA         : False <------------------- a view() on array, not the array itself
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False

>>> image = B[0,:,:] #   slice B into an IMAGE, which will still look as if it is an array
>>> image.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS    : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS    : False
  OWNDATA         : False <----------------- a view() onto an array, not the array itself
  WRITEABLE       : True
  ALIGNED         : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY    : False
>>> image.ndim
2
>>> image.shape
(640, 480)
```

---

Hope you will enjoy the **`.view()`**-s, where used for performance or other reasons and hope you will never have to back-track the hidden-sharing side-effects in production.